# Why time of flight remains same for a projectile even though collision takes place?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, projectile

Why time of flight remains same for a projectile even though collision takes place ?

Suppose a ball is projected with some velocity V with some angle θ the the time of flight is T.

Now if another ball is projected with same angle θ and same velocity V then why time of flight is constant?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time of flight is determined only by the vertical component of velocity - it is the time interval between when the projectile  was released ($y=y_0$) and when it reaches the ground ($y_t=0$).

As the collision is with a vertical wall it acts in the horizontal direction (assuming no friction during the short duration of the collision) and so has no effect on the y-velocity of the projectile, so no effect on flight time.

If the collision resulted in an impulse that was not in the horizontal direction, then the y-velocity and thus the flight time *would* be affected.

Answer (score 1):

If the collision is perfectly elastic then there is no change in the kinetic energy during the collision.  If there were a change in the kinetic energy during the collision then the flight times would be different.  This is analogous to a ball being thrown and encountering no collision.